# ssh username@hostname to ssh hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, host

I have an account on my college server and I access it on linux terminal using
  `ssh {username}@{hostname}.com` 

I was Wondering if there is a way to access this account only by typing.
  `ssh {hostname}`

Comment: yes, see ``man ssh_config``

Comment: Yes, but it will assume that the login name on the destination server is the same as your current login name, at least with the default configuration.

Comment: http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Comment: The default for the username is your current username, so if you create a local account with the same login as you college server, you can su to it, then use ssh without a username

Comment: @EugenRieck unneeded step you can specify username in ssh_config

Comment: Configure this in your `$HOME/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this into your `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host somealias
    HostName example.com
    Port 22
    User myuser
```

You can then type `ssh somealias` and it will actually do a `ssh -p 22 myuser@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say: Yes, *if `username` is the same on both client and server*